# OPA glob pattern that excludes URL's that have a specific part in their path

Tags: glob, opa, open-policy-agent

I'm trying to write an [OPA glob pattern](https://www.openpolicyagent.org/docs/latest/policy-reference/#glob) that matches any URL path that does NOT have the string `/special-part/{whatever}/callback` in it, where `{whatever}` is a path parameter, and this path can potentially have characters before and after it.

I've spun my wheels a good deal and I've gotten nowhere (yet!), so I was wondering if someone could help me out.

Here are some match/no-match cases:

```
// match
/signup/activate-account
/v1/signup/activate-account
/v2/signup/activate-account
/signup/hello/world
/signup/hello-world
/something/else

// no match
/special-part/abc123/callback
/special-part/xyz/callback
/v1/special-part/abc123/callback
/v2/special-part/abc123/callback/123
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this perhaps:

```
package test

match(path) {
    glob.match("**/special-part/*/callback", [], path)
}

match(path) {
    glob.match("**/special-part/*/callback/**", [], path)
}

matches[path] {
    path := input.paths[_]
    not match(path)
}
```

Executable on the [Rego playground](https://play.openpolicyagent.org/p/CeZtfi4ghO)